How to resize the image size in salesforce flow text template?
I have created a text template in Salesforce flow and tried to add an image in it to send emails I have added an image and the code generated for it is below,
When I try to see it in the rich text then it shows the image in its original size(that is big) and the width and height code also gets removed automatically when I switch back to the HTML code view
Can someone look into this and let me know what I am missing and what the issue is?
The image I added in Salesforce and tried to view and then used the URL in img tag

There have been known issues with resizing images in rich text fields using Google Chrome. If that is the browser you are using, they recommend using firefox or another browser. If that is not the case my apologies.
Lit:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387185&type=1
Users additionally reporting issues as recent as 2023:
https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdgGmUAJ/fix-google-chrome-imageresizing-functionality-for-rich-text-fields

Hi Ross Kennedy but I am not using any fields here, I am directly using the image into the flow text template to use it in email body and I am facing issue there I also tried this code,

but while editing again the last style part get deleted automatically

Rather than your current code, , you might benefit more from which would just be pulling the attributes width and height from the IMG tag, rather than applying the inline Style CSS which could be getting scrubbed. It seems your code from your initial post is not available, so if that was your original code my apologies.

I have tried this code also "" but it also gave the same issue then someone told me to use style attribute and add height, and width in it but that also didn't work for me and then I raised the case on stack exchange to get the accurate solution
